# CMAKE, Clang and C++v11 on OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, c++11, compiler-errors, clang

OS X 1.8

CMAKE 2.8.9

Clang `$ clang -v
Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.10.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
Thread model: posix`

CMAKELists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9)
project (Test)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
//Create a C++11 thread from the main program
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

//This function will be called from a thread
void call_from_thread() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    //Launch a thread
    std::thread t1(call_from_thread);

    //Join the thread with the main thread
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

My error:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target Test
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
test/main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'thread' file not found
#include <thread>
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So does the version of Clang not support C++v11 features? This same program does compile under gcc-4.7.1 on OSX 10.8

This reference says it should work `http://www.cpprocks.com/a-comparison-of-c11-language-support-in-vs2012-g-4-7-and-clang-3-1/`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` to the compiler flags?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to provide the `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libc++` flags to the compiler in order to fully activate its C++11 support. This can be done through ccmake (turn on advanced mode (with `t`), and set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`), or through an equivalent directive in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
project(Test)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
```

Comment: Thanks: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
`

Comment: That still doesn't work. The options are passed to the compiler, "make VERBOSE=1" verified that, but C++11 classes such as std::thread or std::function are undefined, despite <thread> and <functional> being included.

Comment: @aledalgrande: Perhaps you also need `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++")`?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++")` was what worked for me

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")` and `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++")` together worked for me. I was running OS X 10.7.5 and LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28).